# jQuery set height of inner divs based on outer

Tags: jquery

Just wondering how I can set the height the heights of 2 divs inside a div holding a flexible jQuery responsive banner.

So the banner has a max-height of 450px but once the screen size reduces the height of the image reduces in aspect ratio, causing the surrounding li - ul, then the banner div to reduce with it.

I then have two divs absolutely positioned, one to top right the other to bottom right.

I want to get the height of the banner height, then set top right div to 70% and the bottom right div to 30%.

Can this also be done on rescale not just at run time?

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks
Geoff

Comment: Share some code of what you have tried?

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's fairly simple as you only need to:

- capture those elements
- loop through them
- get the info from each parent
- feed that info back into it's style

To setup the HTML, I suggest you find a good grid system (ex: [960](http://960.gs/)). This way the parent always controls the percentages and it becomes manageable.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column g70">
        <div class="inner" data-dom="height"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column g30">
        <div class="inner" data-dom="height" data-dom="width"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This allows you to choose whether you want only height to be controlled or also the width. As you play around with responsiveness, it's possible the width becomes important as well for previously added css style. In my experience, responsive google maps is a perfect example to use the `data-dom="width"` attribute.

The best way to set this up in JavaScript, is to create a handler function. Like you do with the most famous equal height scripts.
To give you an untested example in jQuery:

```
// @param {Object} elements: jquery selector ($('[data-dom]'))
function dimensionHandler(elements){
    elements.each(function(){
       var el = $(this),
           parent = el.parent(),
           isWidth = el.data('dom') === 'width',
           isHeight = el.data('dom') === 'height',
           defW = '100%',
           defH = 'auto',
           w = isWidth ? parent.width() : defW,
           h = isHeight ? parent.height() : defH;

       el.css({
           width: w || defW, // if width was 0 use 100%
           height: h || defH // if height was 0 use auto
       });
   });
}
```

Using the default css values as backup, you can get around hidden elements.
Now you only need to setup some events, and call the handler function.

```
$(function(){
   var win = $(window),
       elements = $('[data-dom]');

   win.on('load', function () {
       dimensionHandler(elements);
   });

   win.on('resize', function () {
       //throttle(function () {
           dimensionHandler(elements);
       //}, 200);         
   });
});
```

Notice I commented out a [throttle/debounce](http://jsfiddle.net/amyseqmedia/dD99u/37/) function. As the `resize` event works at rapid speeds, it helps to slow down the execution of this handler function. And let your browser/device breathe a little before it chokes on browser reflow. I'll leave the throttle/debounce option to you. GL!